# Tap Gesture Not Firing

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using the following code to attach gesture recognizers to a custom view. But for some reason I am not able to get the gestures to work.

```
 for(NSString *option in _options) {

        UIView *blind = [self createBlind:option];
        blind.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        blind.tag = index;

        [self addSubview:blind];

        [self addGravityBehaviorToBlind:blind];
        [self addCollisionBehaviorToBlind:blind];
        [self addElasticityBehaviorToBlind:blind];
        [self registerGestureRecognizer:blind];

        _spacingY += 44;

        index++;
    }
}

-(void) registerGestureRecognizer:(UIView *) blind {

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(blindTapped:)];
    [blind addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
}

-(void) blindTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) recognizer {  <-- THIS NEVER GETS CALLED

    NSLog(@"blindTapped");


}
```

For some reason the blindTapped method never gets called even if I tap on the blind view.

UPDATE:

Yes, I see the views on the screen. The views (blind) is a subview in another view. The parent view gets added to the controller.view. There is no place where I have disabled interaction.

Here is the createBlind method:

```
-(UIView *) createBlind:(NSString *) option {

    UIView *blind = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, _spacingY, 200, 44)];
    blind.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    blind.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;

    UILabel *optionTitleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, blind.bounds.size.width, blind.bounds.size.height)];
    optionTitleLabel.text = option;
    optionTitleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans" size:17];
    optionTitleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    optionTitleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    [blind addSubview:optionTitleLabel];

    return blind;
}
```

I have removed all the gravity and UIKit methods but still I am not able to trigger the tap gesture.

**SOLUTION:**

When adding the custom view to my controller.view I was not setting the frame. Once the frame was setup everything worked.

Comment: have you tried to add [self bringSubviewToFront:blind];

Comment: Try taking out the addGravity addCollision and addElasticity and see if it works then. What are those methods doing btw?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code you've posted. Post the code for the createBlind method. Are you seeing your custom views, and are they displaying the correct dynamic behaviors?

Comment: in `touchesBegan` does your event register on the view you're intending? Is this view nested in a view that disables user interaction?

Comment: Updated the original question with more information.

Comment: Found the solution. I was not setting the frame for my main parent view.

Comment: Than add your solution as an answer and mark it as correct the next days!